# Why telegram emoji numbers are not deleted when removing special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a telegram bot and I want to remove all special characters and just returns numbers and A-Z,but the problem is that my regex pattern can remove any emojies except numbers like this :1️⃣2️⃣3️⃣4️⃣5️⃣6️⃣

I want to delete emoji numbers too

So this is my pattern :

```
text = '1️⃣Hi =) 1.This regex removes 2️⃣all special 6️⃣characters like this !@$#%^&*()_+=~`/\><.⚠️4️⃣'

text.toUpperCase().match(/[a-z]+|\d+(?:\.\d+)?/gi)
    .map((m) => (isNaN(m) ? m : +m))

//Current output : 
// [1,'HI',1,'THIS','REGEX','REMOVES',2,'ALL', 'SPECIAL',6,'CHARACTERS', 'LIKE','THIS']


//What I want : 
// ['HI',1,'THIS','REGEX','REMOVES','ALL', 'SPECIAL','CHARACTERS', 'LIKE','THIS']
```

Also I don't know why it removed the last number emoji from string! (4️⃣)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These numbers are emojis. To remove them, too, use the following:

```js
text = '1️⃣Hi =) 1.This regex removes 2️⃣all special 6️⃣characters like this !@$#%^&*()_+=~`/\><.⚠️4️⃣'

console.log(
  text.toUpperCase().match(/[a-z]+|(?!\d\uFE0F\u20E3)\d+(?:\.\d+)?/gi)
    .map((m) => (isNaN(m) ? m : +m))
)
```

The `(?!\d\uFE0F\u20E3)` negative lookahead will fail any match of `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` when the first digit is a part of the numeric emojis.